# Why am I getting this border around eclipse windows?

Tags: 16.04, gui, eclipse

I installed elementary-os desktop and removed it completely using ppa-purge.
Now when I start eclipse I get this nasty border around the dialogs and some dialogs keeps extending horizontally. Any idea how to fix this?

I installed the elementary-desktop using

1. elementary-os/daily
2. elementary-os/os-patches

PPAs.

And removed both using ppa-purge.

- OS : Ubuntu 16.04
- DE : XFCE

[image]

Comment: ppa-purge doesn't remove ElementryOS, it downgrades packages to ubuntu versions. Thus as my understanding, you could have ElementaryOS packages still in your system because there was not an ubuntu version of it. such as themes and config files. As far as the image posted, it appears that there are two windows managers drawing borders for the app, and that the compositor is off or missing.

Comment: Hmm.. But why this happens for only eclipse then?